# Tensor product of representations of a product group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Given some group $G$ that can be written as product of two other groups

$$G = G_1 \times G_2 $$

and some representation of this group written in terms of representations of $G_1$ and $G_2$

$$R = (R_1 ,R_2)$$

Is the tensor product of this representation with some other representation simply

$$ R \otimes R' = (R_1 ,R_2) \otimes (R_1' ,R_2') = (R_1 \otimes R_1',R_2\otimes R_2') ?$$

If not, what else?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $R = (R_1,R_2)$?

Comment: If $\left(R_1, R_2\right)$ means $R_1 \otimes R_2$, then the answer to the first question is "yes".